# Current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction

Tags: postgresql, connection, node-modules, amazon-sqs, jobs

sql: 'select * from "jobs" where "type" = ? and (meta->>\'Id\')::UUID = ? limit ?' }
200415/014921.244, [log,error,sqs-consumer] message: select * from "jobs" where "type" = $1 and (meta->>'Id')::UUID = $2 limit $3 - current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block, stack: error: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    at Connection.parseE (/home/ubuntu/server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:11)

Comment: How to fix this issue?

Comment: Actions you need. 1. Format your code, if that is part of a larger block post the larger block. 2. Describe what your are attempting to accomplish. 3. Describe how you submitted the query/block. 4. Read help section [ask].

Answer (score 2):

If a statement in a transaction causes an error, the transaction is aborted. All following statements in the same transaction will cause the error you observe. The transaction is doomed and can only be rolled back.

You should handle errors caused by SQL statements and roll back the transaction when they happen.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I see this error for the first time, the application was running fine since yesterday, Do I need to clear out all the jobs in the Database and check again

Comment: No, you just have to handle errors correctly. You should figure out which statement causes the error and fix it (hint: look in the PostgreSQL log file). But you were asking about "current transaction is aborted", not the original error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed, I had to clear out all the jobs, and the application is up and running in Stage now.